# What happens when PAMGuard freezes (due to memory issues) while creating an LTSA?

Tags: pam, pamguard, troubleshooting, ltsa

I'm using PAMGuard to process some recordings and I keep having an issue where it is freezing. I'm trying to create an LTSA at the same time as using the GPL detector (for blue whale A/B calls). I have run just the GPL detector in the past without it stalling, but when I added the LTSA module, the software crashes after running about 24 hours of recordings. I know it's stalling because of the LTSA because PAMGuard throws a warning on the main panel of the software (see screenshot below). Is there anything I can do to fix how often it crashes? The files I am processing are sampled at 384kHz. I'm decimating them to 400Hz to run the GPL detector but I'm trying to create a full bandwidth LTSA. Is this just too much for PAMGuard to handle? See the second screenshot below for the DOS window

[image: Warning from PAMGuard when it freezes]

[image: DOS window from PAMGuard when it crashes]

Comment: This seems to be a bug in PAMGuard, so it might be more appropriate to send it to support@pamguard.org

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there is a bug in the GPL detector. Can you make sure you are using the very latest version of PAMGuard and, if so, then please send this to support@pamguard.org along with your .psfx file and an example of the audio data.

Comment: That is not a memory error, but an indexing error. Can you get the rest of the text out of that window rather than just sending a screen shot. It says how to do this at the top of the window - right click on the border to get a menu, then edit  / select all, edit / copy, then paste.